# Add css class to list items except last in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list which values are generated from a database using php and mysql.

```
<div id="articles">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($articles as article) { ?>
            <li><a href="/articles/<?php echo $article['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['name']; ?> </a> </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery to add a css class to every item in that list except the last one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
//then you can select all `li` elements under `#articles` except the last one like

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#articles li:not(:last)').addClass('myclass')
})
```

```css
.myclass {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="articles">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/articles/2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/articles/3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

You can do it with css only

```css
#articles li {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
#articles li:last-child {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="articles">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/articles/1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/articles/2">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/articles/3">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I do have that in my code i must of stuffed up the copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="articles">
<ul>
    <?php 
         $count =count($articles);
         foreach ($articles as article) {
           $counter++;
            If($count==$counter)
                 $class='something';
             Else
                 $class='';
 ?>
               <li><a href="/articles/<?php echo     $article['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['name']; ?>     </a> </li>
        <?php
             }
         ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Use class variable in li now.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same thing using PHP also by adding one more condition in your code.

```
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    if(end($articles) == $article) {
    ?>
       <li><a href="/articles/<?php echo $article['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['name']; ?> </a></li>
    <?php
    }
    else{ ?>
       <li class="myclass"><a href="/articles/<?php echo $article['name']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['name']; ?> </a></li>
   <?php
      }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but due to using MVC framework this seems a little cumbersome on the view. thank anyway though

Comment: Sorry then no other way without if condition you need to us javascript as  per the @ArunPJohny answer.

Comment: yeh javascript seems to be the solution my friend